# Trying to send data from actionmethod to a static method in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send data from ActionResult method Index to a static method PopulatePlant in MVC, but while sending i am getting error:

> the name doesn't exist in the current context.

Basically in the HttpPost method i am receiving a value in Tempdata["EmpId"] and now i want to post this value along with value returning from PopulatePlant() in "MasterPage" view .

But first how to Send value in TempData["EmpId"] inside static method PopulatePlant()?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormData person)
{
 TempData["EmpId"] = person.EmpId.ToString();
 FormData Detail = new FormData();
 Detail.PlantName = PopulatePlant();       
 return View("MasterPage");
}

private static List<SelectListItem> PopulatePlant()
{
    List<SelectListItem> PName = new List<SelectListItem>();
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select nvl(count(1),0) from Tdc_Product1 where TDC_NO=:COLUMN1", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":COLUMN1", TempData["EmpId"]);
    return PName;
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Which name doesn't exist in the current context? `PouplatePlant` method is not returning any values. You might want to start from correcting it.

Comment: Why is the method static? Also, can you not get EmpID in the posted model FormData? If so add a parameter to PopulatePlant and pass it in!

Comment: you should do `Detail.PlantName = <YourControllerName>.PopulatePlant();`

Comment: "how to Send value in TempData["EmpId"] inside static method"...well, just like any other method: declare the method with a parameter `private static List<SelectListItem> PopulatePlant(string empID)` and when you call it, pass in a value: `Detail.PlantName = PopulatePlant(TempData["EmpId"].ToString());` Lastly you can then do `command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":COLUMN1", empId);` using the method parameter. Passing parameters to methods is something you learn on day one of programming generally...it's hard to know what your actual difficulty is really?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya if i store value in Index method  like this int EmpId = person.EmpId; and use it like command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":COLUMN1", person.EmpId.ToString()); then it is throwing error or as shown above If i am trying to use Tempdata["EmpID"] instead that, again it is also throwing error.bascically i want to use that value in static method

Comment: You should change `PopulatePlant` method to accept one parameter `int empid` and call `PopulatePlant` from Index method with proper parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the value to your method as a parameter, the same way you would pass data around between methods and objects in any program:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormData person)
{
 FormData Detail = new FormData();
 Detail.PlantName = PopulatePlant(person.EmpId.ToString()); //pass the relevant value to the method (using TempData is not really needed here)
 return View("MasterPage");
}

private static List<SelectListItem> PopulatePlant(string empId) //declare that the method will receive a string parameter
{
    List<SelectListItem> PName = new List<SelectListItem>();
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select nvl(count(1),0) from Tdc_Product1 where TDC_NO=:COLUMN1", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":COLUMN1", empId); //use the method's parameter
    return PName;
}
```